# want to get images from flicker but i get undefine

Tags: reactjs

i want to get images from flicker but when i console my object it gives me undefine ..
here is my code

```
loadimages(e)
{ e.preventDefault();
 this.setState({spinner:true});
 console.log('spinner');
//  axios.get(`https://www.pexels.com/`).then(res=>{
//    console.log(this.state.spinner);
//    this.setState({images:res.data,spinner:false});
//  });

axios.post("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne? 
tags=kitten&format=json") 
.then((response) => {
console.log('hellodata',response.data.items);
this.setState({
    images: response.data.items,
    spinner:false
});
console.log('images',this.state.images);

 }).catch(function(err){
console.log(err);
})
```

}

Comment: Do you have result in `response.data.items`? Logging the `state` won't work

Comment: no i got undefine

Comment: i used both but same result

Comment: i dont have any end point

Comment: U want to ge images from flickr but using`post` on axios on that url. I used postman for `https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne? 
tags=kitten&format=json` and it returns data